# Translate complex query involving MAX() to querybuilder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to translate the following query into queryBuilder:

```
SELECT 
    app.*, 
    MAX((draft_config_app.country = "US" AND draft_config_app.channel_id = 87) OR companion_app.signing_status <> 2) AS badcount 
FROM app left join draft_config_app ON draft_config_app.app_id = app.id 
LEFT JOIN app_country_tracking ON app_country_tracking.app_id = app.id 
LEFT JOIN companion_app ON companion_app.app_country_tracking_id = app_country_tracking_id 
WHERE app.partner_code = "SL" 
    AND app.signing_status = 2 
GROUP BY app.id 
HAVING badcount = 0 OR badcount IS NULL;
```

I've tried the following:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(['a', 'MAX((d.country = :country AND d.channel = :channel) OR c.signingStatus <> :status) as badcount'])
        ->from("Aip\CommonBundle\Entity\App", "a")
        ->leftJoin("a.draftConfigApps", "d")
        ->leftJoin('a.appCountryTracking', 't')
        ->leftJoin('t.companionApp', 'c')
        ->where("a.signingStatus = :status")
        ->andWhere('a.partner = :partner')
        ->setParameter("status", AppSigningStatusEnum::SUCCESS)
        ->setParameter('country', $country)
        ->setParameter('channel', $channel)
        ->setParameter('partner', $partner)
        ->groupBy('a.id')
        ->having('badcount = 0 OR badcount IS NULL');
```

But I get an error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 25: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got '='
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is the `MAX(...)` in the select, but I have no idea what's the proper way to recreate that portion of the query in doctrine's query builder.